# Action Replay for PC processes?

Tags: memory, process, action, freeze, replay

Back in my C64 and Amiga days, a company named Datel sold a cartridge called "Action Replay" that froze the running process (game) and let you modify its data. You could then either save the modified process to disk (permanently changing the game) or continue playing it.

Is there a way to do this with PC processes? I know how to pause a process and modify its memory, but am unsure how to save the process memory to disk as a new executable.

Answer (score 0):

OllyDbg with the OllyDump plugin is a good combination to dump a process. It will correct the entry point address, import function addresses and anything else that needs to be fixed. It is a powerful combination but of course it lacks the ease of use of the Final Cartridge.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, but I was wondering more about doing it myself, rather than relying on a third-party solution that I probably can't legally distribute. I'll take a look at OllyDbg anyway and see if maybe it supports a command-line option to do what you said. Thanks, and I noticed you said Final Cartridge instead of Action Replay. :) I also had both carts in the old days. :)

Comment: If you are looking for an command line tool you can also check out microsoft procdump. However keep in mind that dumping the bits is just half of the story. You also need to fix the entry point and imports! ... and it is good to see that there are other people out there still rembering the c64 times ;=)